# C++ program with command line arguments returning the wrong answer

Tags: c++, algorithm, command-line, command-line-arguments

I wrote a C++ implementation of the Euclidean Algorithm and I am wondering why it outputs the incorrect answer when I use command line parameters. Otherwise, it works correctly.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int gcd(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    if(argc != 3){
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " a b" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }   

    //Check to see if argv[1] is an integer 
    std::istringstream ss1(argv[1]);
    int a;
    if(!(ss1 >> a)){
        std::cout << "Invalid number " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //Check to see if argv[1] is an integer 
    std::istringstream ss2(argv[1]);
    int b;
    if(!(ss2 >> b)){
        std::cout << "Invalid number " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << gcd(a, b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}   

//calculates the gcd of 2 integers
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

And here what I entered as arguments and the output.

```
gcd 6 7
6

gcd 90 10
90
```

As you've probably already guessed, the program just gives the first argument I give it as output but only for command line arguments. What's going on here?

Comment: `std::istringstream ss2(argv[1]);` is that meant to be `argv[2]`?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always reading the first parameter (`argv[1]`), second one (`argv[2]`) is not used. With your code, you have `a` equal to `b`, so, first call to `gcd(a,b)` calls `gcd(b,a%b)` which is `gcd(b,0)`, returning `b`....equal to `a` (if you follow)!

So whatever is your second argument, the program will always return the value of the first one!

Replace `std::istringstream ss2(argv[1]);` by `std::istringstream ss2(argv[2]);`

Comment: Thanks a lot, can't believe I didn't see that!